# InvalidReferenceException with Freemarker when I try to show hyphen

Tags: freemarker, spark-java, spark-framework

I'm using Freemarker with Spark Framework in the version 2.5.5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-template-freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to save a textarea with line breaks and hyphens and show the value, but I'm receiving an error that it's not clear to me.

For example, to save, I'm using:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="listaIngredientes" 
name="listaIngredientes"></textarea>
```

And to show what I save (from `visualizar.ftl` freemarker file):

```
<p><pre>${ingrediente.listaIngredientes}</pre></p>
```

This works very well for most of cases, including to show line breaks. But if I try to add a hyphen in the textarea with a space before some text, I receive this error (in `input` or `<pre>`):
    freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)

To be more clear, I will show some texts that work and some that show the error:

- success: `sometext`
- success: `sometext-sometext`
- success: `sometext- sometext`
- error: `sometext -sometext`
- error: `sometext - sometext`

I would like to know how prevent for this problem. The error is not clear about the problem.

Thanks!

Full log error:

```
mai 21, 2017 4:02:47 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger error
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> ingrediente.listaIngredientes  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 17]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${ingrediente.listaIngredientes}  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 15]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:355)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
    at spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine.render(FreeMarkerEngine.java:69)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:61)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:58)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:86)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:62)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> ingrediente.listaIngredientes  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 17]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${ingrediente.listaIngredientes}  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 15]
----
    at spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine.render(FreeMarkerEngine.java:72)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:61)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl$1.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:58)
    at spark.TemplateViewRouteImpl.render(TemplateViewRouteImpl.java:86)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:62)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> ingrediente.listaIngredientes  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 17]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${ingrediente.listaIngredientes}  [in template "ingredientes/visualizar.ftl" at line 103, column 15]
----
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:355)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
    at spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine.render(FreeMarkerEngine.java:69)
    ... 20 more
[qtp952081498-16] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/ingredientes/visualizar/1030989562] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]
```

Comment: It seems that `ingrediente.listaIngredientes` is indeed `null` in that case, but not because FreeMarker makes a `null` out of it. FreeMarker doesn't care what the string value contains, it doesn't parse it. Certainly something else tries to parse the submitted content and ends up with a `null`.

Comment: agree with ddekany, try to debug the execution server-side and check the value of `ingrediente` and `ingrediente.listaIngredientes` just before the `FreeMarkerEngine.render()` is called